# Significance of Alpha and Beta with regards to matrix multiplication.

Tags: matrices

I'm learning a library for doing GEMM on the GPU. There are some things in the library which I don't quite understand.

[This](http://clmathlibraries.github.io/clBLAS/group__GEMM.html#ga29d93e46c106ce34249f21e436ed7102) is the function call, for reference.

The function asks for alpha and beta, and calls them the factor of matrix A and C respectively. What is the significance of those values? How are they calculated, or what effect do they have? I played around with those numbers in the example file for that function, and they do change the values in the output matrix, but it's not clear how.

Answer (score 1):

GEMM funcion is a matrix-matrix multiply in the form:

$\mathbf C$=$\alpha \mathbf A\mathbf B$+$\beta\mathbf C$

So, for example, if $\beta=1$ and $\alpha=1$
we will add the product of $\mathbf{AB}$ to the previous value of matrix $\mathbf C$.
and if $\beta=0$ and $\alpha=2$, we will replace the value of $\mathbf C$ with twice the product of $\mathbf{AB}$.

A good source for BLAS and LAPACK libraries is Intel MKL manual (that's the one I use).
https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/468480